# strange behaviour with FF that "und\x65\x66\151n\x65\144" translated to "d"

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following code, when executed in this special FireFox(64.0.2)

```
if (typeof window.RadControlsNamespace=="und\x65\x66\151n\x65\144"){window.RadControlsNamespace= {} ; }
```

"und\x65\x66\151n\x65\144" gets interpreted strangely as "d", but for other FF with the same version it's correctly interpreted as "underfined".

What could possibly the reason behind this, custom setting for the browser?

The faulty browser has this option "javascript.options.strict=true" in prefs.js

Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. How have you determined that this string is interpreted as "d"?

Comment: It was displayed in the console. You will see this when you have the "javascript.options.strict" set to true in FF "about:config" page

Answer (score 0):

`"\151"` and `"\144"` sequences do throw in strict-mode:

> *SyntaxError: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the "0o" prefix instead*.

```js
(_ => {
  'use strict';
  console.log("\144");
})();
```

You can replace these characters with their proper escape sequence though:

```js
(_ => {
  'use strict';
  console.log("und\x65\x66\x69n\x65\x64")
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I have this "javascript.options.strict" set to true in FF "about:config" page.

Set it to "false" solved the issue.